# Whether one array contains the same element with another array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to recreate 'mastermind', handling five letter words instead of colors.

I have a five letter word, lets say `"Alice"`, and I am splitting that into an array called `answer_array`. Then I am prompting the user to input a five letter word, and then that is split into `guess_array`. I am trying to compare if `guess_array` contains any of the same letters in the `answer_array`, and if so, it will return with appropriate feedback.

This is along the lines of what I am trying to achieve:

```
guess_array.each { |x| puts guess_array[x] == answer_array[x]}
```

However it pings back an error message:

```
StringTest.rb:18:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
    from StringTest.rb:18:in `block in <main>'
    from StringTest.rb:18:in `each'
    from StringTest.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an array which contains only the common elements of two arrays using the [`&` (or set intersection) operator](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-26):

```
> [1, 2, 3] & [2, 3, 4]
=> [2, 3]

> [1,2,3] & [4,5,6]
=> []
```

If you don't need to return the actual shared values, just check for emptiness on the intersection and get a boolean:

```
> ([1,2,3] & [4,5,6]).any?
=> false
> ([1,2,3] & [3,5,6]).any?
=> true
```

Regarding the error you're currently getting: what your code is actually doing is iterating over each element in `guess_array`, where the inner variable in the block at each iteration, `x`, is the array element itself. `x` isn't an index, it's a string value in your case. Take a look:

```
> ['a', 'b', 'c'].each{ |s| puts s }
a
b
c
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

So obviously something like `my_array['a']` wouldn't work.

If you wanted to iterate with both a value and an index, you could invoke [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
> ['a','b','c'].each_with_index{ |s, i| puts "value is #{s} and index is #{i}" }
value is a and index is 0
value is b and index is 1
value is c and index is 2
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

And that would allow you to perform lookups based on the current index of the array in some other array. But for your particular problem this probably isn't the best solution -- use the set intersection.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand that now. I really appreciate it!

Comment: `['a','b','a','c'] & ['a','a','d','a'] #=> ['a']`. Corbin, is that what you want, or do you want the return value to be `['a','a']` or possibly something else?